# R. RCurl 400 Bad Request

Tags: r, rcurl, geturl

I try to send a request to API, use RCurl library.

My code:

```
start = "2018-07-30"
end = "2018-08-15"

api_request <- paste("https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data.csv?id=34904255&date1=",
                     start,
                     "&date2=",
                     end,
                     "&dimensions=ym:s:searchEngine&metrics=ym:s:visits&dimensions=ym:s:<attribution>SearchPhrase&filters=ym:s:<attribution>SearchPhrase!~'some|phrases|here'&limit=100000&oauth_token=OAuth_token_here", sep="")
s <- getURL(api_request)
```

And every time I try to do it I have the response "Error 400" or "Bad Request" if I use getUrlContent instead. When I just open this url in my browser - it works correctly.
I still couldn't find any solution for this problem, so if somebody knows something about it - please help me, kind man =)

Comment: Have you found any solution?
Got the same problem with Y.Metrica API

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can use in case the URL is right. First you can add the following parameter to the `getURL` function. Setting the parameter `followlocation` equal TRUE allows to follow any "Location:" header that the server returns as part of the HTTP headers. Processing is recursive, PHP will follow any "Location:" header.

```
> s <- getURL(url1, .opts=curlOptions(followlocation = TRUE))
```

If this is not working an alternative way is to use the `XML` package by calling the `htmlParse` method instead of `getURL`

```
> library(XML)
> s <- htmlParse(api_request)
```

Another approach would be to use the `httr` package and call the `GET` function:

```
> library(httr)
> s <- GET(api_request)
```